# Can we determine a return type for array elements in php?

Tags: php, function, return-type, php-7

Is it possible to dertermine the elements type of the returning array in a function?

For example, if the elements should be floats:

```
class test{
    /**
     * This should return an array containing float values,
     * but I get a fatal error instead
     */
    public static function doStuff() : float[] {
        return [ 10.3, 12.8 ];
    }
}
```

Comment: `float[]` -> `array`, as you are returning an array, if you wanted to make sure you were populating that array with floats you can cast with `(float)`

Comment: @cmorrissey Yeah but that will allow me to return any type inside the array...

Comment: Not yet, in the same way that you can't yet use an argument typehint of `objectType[]`, only of `array`.... there was an RFC for the latter, but IIRC it was rejected, though it may simply be dormant

Comment: Humm okay.. I will see if i find alternatives and post for you guys. Thanks @MarkBaker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't type-check the contents of an array like that.

If you really insist on doing this, you could create your own collection class that wraps around the array and ensures the type of its elements:

```
class FloatCollection
{
    private $array = [];

    public function __construct($array = [])
    {
        foreach ($array as $value) {
            $this->add($value);
        }
    }

    public function add(float $value)
    {
        $this->array[] = $value;
    }

    ...
}
```

Then you can type check for that:

```
public static function doStuff() : FloatCollection
{
    return new FloatCollection([10.3, 12.8]);
}
```

But it might be a lot of unnecessary work for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: _it might be a lot of unnecessary work for what you're trying to achieve_ Yes, if we're talking about primitive types. Imagine this concept applied to complex objects like `getControllers() : Controller[]`

Comment: It would make much more sense if PHP had generics, since you wouldn't have to create a separate collection class for each type. Since that's not the case, I personally try not to expose whole arrays whenever I can, and I generally don't mix types in my arrays. If that isn't 'safe enough' for your case, then this approach will get the job done with some extra code.